# jquery ajax php strange result of json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

JS

```
var data = {item:'value'}
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(jqXHR,status,text){
        console.log(jqXHR,status,text);
    },
    success: function(ajax_response){
        console.log(ajax_response);
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if($_POST["item"] == "value"){
        $ajax_response = [];
        $ajax_response["response1"] = 'value1';
        $ajax_response["response2"] = 'value2';
        echo json_encode($ajax_response);
    }   
?>
```

All seem to be ok but thrown a parsererror SyntaxError:

> readyState:4
>
> responseText:"["false"]{"response1":"value1","response2":"value2"}↵↵"
>
> status:200
>
> statusText:"OK" 
>   ... 
>   parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token { in JSON at position 9

I have tried also `json_last_error()` but return `0` (`JSON_ERROR_NONE` No error has occurred)

I don't understand why json_encode() add a `["false"]` before json string result ?

Comment: It wouldn't, you **must** have other code which outputs it.

Comment: add actual code for the response section

Comment: Yes I have there only one example (... can't post ... a lot of code ...) ... I think ... you have reason .... Must check if some don't output the `[false]`

Comment: Check your entire project for `echo json_encode(['false']);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I found it Thank you. What you suggest ... (you have more experience) I will delete this question or leave it here ?

Comment: Glad to help.. entirely up to you.